# how to grow mysql dynamically

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

we want to make a website, where we are using Pandora technique and using mysql database.
in our website we want to keep one table in which we add columns on run time and update table and this process goes on.

My question is that how can we  grow our database(mysql) dynamically?

Comment: Hmmm not sure if you have to use only MySQL, but based on the requirements described you should have a look at mongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

> we are using Pandora technique

This had me a bit confused - at first I though you meant you dressed up as tall blue aliens and plugged your pony tails into other animals then I [found this on Google](http://pandoratechnique.com/#).

While neither of these seem to have anything to do with sensible database design, neither does `keep one table in which we add columns on run time`

Sorry, but your question is vague, provides no background / constraints / objectives and the only concrete facts it contains are absurd.